# Colour format in registry

Tags: windows-registry, colors

In `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM` "AccentColor" has a value of

```
ffe37c00(hex)
```

What format is this and how would I go about converting an RGB colour into a format that works in the registry?

Comment: Where do you want the change in color to reflect?

Comment: It is likely RGBA or ARGB, but most likely RGBA.  So each pair of hex characters is colour and FF would be the red value, e3 is green value, and 7c would be the blue value. 00 would be the alpha (transparency) channel. Not an answer because I don't know for certain, but it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out. It's RGBA just backwards so ABGR therefore in this case:

alpha: ff, blue: e3, green: 7c, red: 00